# Welche Sprachen sprichst du? vs. Welche Sprache sprichst du?

Tags: difference, grammatical-number

In allen Deutsch-als-Fremdsprache-Lehrwerken in den ersten Lektionen (*Hallo! / Wie heißt du? / Woher kommst du? / Wo wohnst du?* usw.) steht folgende Frage:

> *Welche Sprach**en** sprichst du?*

Ich nehme mal an, man geht davon aus, dass sein Gesprächspartner mehr als eine Sprache spricht, deswegen wird die Frage im Plural formuliert, oder? Wäre es möglich, diese Frage (im Vorstellung-und-Kennenlernen-Kontext) im Singular zu bilden → *Welche Sprach**e** sprichst du?* oder ist es absolut fehlerhaft?

Comment: Eigentlich bezieht sich diese frage nicht zur deutschen Sprache. Der Unterschied zwischen Plural und Singular würde ja die gleichen Unterschiede in den meisten Sprachen geben. Ist also eigentlich Off-topic m.M.n.

Answer (score 11):

Beide Versionen sind grammatikalisch völlig korrekt und gebräuchlich. Allerdings haben sie eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung.

1. **Welche Sprach*en* sprichst du?**

Der Plural drückt hier aus, dass die Zahl der Sprachen unbestimmt ist (da der Sprecher sie noch nicht kennt). Dabei wird nichts vom Sprecher im Voraus angenommen, dieser unbestimmte Plural umfasst auch die Möglichkeit, dass der Gesprächspartner eine oder null Sprachen spricht (im zweiten Fall wäre die Kommunikation natürlich schwierig). A propos "Sprachen spricht": Das "sprechen" ist hier eigentlich eine Verkürzung von "sprechen *können*".

2. **Welche Sprach*e* sprichst du?**

Hier wird explizit nach einer einzigen Sprache gefragt. Je nach Kontext ist "sprechen" hier **keine** Verkürzung von "sprechen können", sondern der Sprecher fragt nach der konkreten Sprache, die sein Gesprächspartner aktuell im Gespräch verwendet (zum Beispiel bei Verständigungsschwierigkeiten). In deinem Kontext mit Kennenlernfragen ergibt das allerdings wenig Sinn. Die andere Interpretationsmöglichkeit ist, dass hier nach "der" Sprache des Gesprächspartners, also der Muttersprache, gefragt wird (also auch wieder eine Verkürzung: "Welche Sprache sprichst du *normalerweise*?"). Das würde auch in deinem Beispiel passen.

Answer (score 5):

> Welche Sprache sprichst du?

ist grammatisch durchaus richtig.

Jedoch wäre die Frage, in welcher Kommunikationssituation so ein Satz konkret auftreten könnte. Wendet man sich an Personen, von denen man nicht weiß, welche Sprache/n sie sprechen, wird man natürlicherweise fragen

> Welche Sprachen sprichst du?

weil man nicht weiß, wie viele es sind, und es ist der natürlichere Ansatz, hier nach einer unbestimmten Menge zu fragen (ausgedrückt durch Plural), anstatt die Menge künstlich auf 1 (ausgedrückt durch Singular) festzulegen.

Die Verwendung der Einzahl wirkt auf den Angesprochenen in der beschriebenen Kommunikationssituation irritierend. Wäre ich der Gefragte, würde ich auf "Welche Sprache sprichst du" wahrscheinlich antworten:

> Wie "sprichst du"? Du meinst jetzt konkret, oder was?

Vorstellbar wäre jedoch: Man hört jemanden z.B. auf der Straße telefonieren und findet den Klang der Sprache schön, kann die Sprache aber nicht erkennen. Dann könnte man sich an den Sprecher wenden und fragen:

> Welche Sprache sprichst du denn da?

oder

> Was ist das für eine Sprache, die du da sprichst?

Nota bene: Hier ist die Rede von einer konkreten Sprache (Einzahl), nicht von einer unbekannten Menge von Sprachen.

(Ich hatte mal so einen Fall. Das war an der Uni Tübingen in einem Foyer, zu einer Zeit, als es noch keine Handys, dafür aber Münztelefone gab. Da sprach eine Studentin eine mir unbekannte, bei ihr sehr schön klingende Sprache, und ich fragte sie, was das für eine Sprache war.)

Comment: Jetzt aber bitte auch verraten, welche Sprache die Studentin gesprochen hat, Latein wirds nicht gewesen sein.

Answer (score 2):

Du lernst eine Fremdsprache (in diesem Fall Deutsch). Wuerdest du nun fragen

> Welche Sprache sprichst du?

wuerdest du damit implizit unterstellen, dass dein Gegenueber im Gegensatz zu dir keine Fremdsprache beherrscht und nur eine einzige Sprache spricht. Das koennte als unhoeflich aufgefasst werden, weswegen man immer im Plural fragen sollte, selbst wenn sich am Ende herausstellt, dass dein Gesprachspartner doch nur eine Sprache spricht - was in der heutigen Zeit doch recht selten vor kommt, ein wenig Grundkenntnisse in ein oder zwei weiteren Sprachen haben die meisten.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn ich diese Frage stelle, benutze ich ja schon eine Sprache (in diesem Fall Deutsch) und gehe davon aus, dass mein Gegenüber diese Sprache versteht. Also frage ich doch nach weiteren Sprachen, oder? Und da ich vermutlich nicht weiß, wieviele Sprachen mein Gegenüber spricht, verwende ich die allgemeinste Form und das ist der Plural (der Plural lässt die Zahl unbestimmt, auch Null wäre eingeschlossen).

Comment: Gegenbeispiel: Eine Gruppe von Leuten unterhält sich im Zug in einer fremden Sprache. Meine damalige und ich hören sie sprechen und überlegen uns, was das sei. Irgendwann steht sie auf und fragt »Entschuldigen Sie, wir haben uns gewundert, *welche Sprache sprechen Sie?«*

Comment: Richtig, in diesem Fall fragt man nach genau einer Sprache. Im oben beschriebenen Fall bleibt die Frage nach einer unbestimmten Anzahl von Sprachen.